# get same output when making prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm new in ML. I am trying to make a basic example of image classification containing digits. I created my own dataset but I get a bad accuracy (11%). I have 246 items for training and 62 for testing. 
Here is my code:

```py
#TRAINING

def load_data(input_path, img_height, img_width):
  data = []
  labels = []
  for imagePath in os.listdir(input_path):  
    labels_path = os.path.join(input_path, imagePath)
    if os.path.isdir(labels_path): 
      for img_path in os.listdir(labels_path):
        labels.append(imagePath)
        img_full_path = os.path.join(labels_path, img_path)
        img = image.load_img(img_full_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)) 
        img = image.img_to_array(img)
        data.append(img)
  return data, labels



  train_data = []
  train_labels = []
  test_data = []
  test_labels = []
  train_data, train_labels = load_data(train_path, 28, 28)
  test_data, test_labels = load_data(test_path, 28, 28)


  train_data = np.array(train_data)
  train_data = train_data / 255.0
  train_data = tf.reshape(train_data, train_data.shape[:3])
  train_labels = np.array(train_labels)
  train_labels = np.asfarray(train_labels,float)


  test_data = np.array(test_data) 
  test_data = tf.reshape(test_data, test_data.shape[:3])
  test_data = test_data / 255.0
  test_labels = np.array(test_labels)


 model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
  ])


  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


  model.fit(train_data, train_labels, batch_size=10, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=246)

  test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels, steps=1)
  print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

```py
#CLASSIFICATION

def classify(input_path):
    if os.path.isdir(input_path):
        images = []
        for file_path in os.listdir(input_path):
            full_path = os.path.join(input_path, file_path)
            img_tensor = preprocess_images(full_path, 28, 28, "L")
            images.append(img_tensor)
        images = np.array(images)
        images = tf.reshape(images,(images.shape[0],images.shape[2],images.shape[3]))
        predictions = model.predict(images, steps = 1)


        for i in range(len(predictions)):
            print("Image", i , "is", np.argmax(predictions[i]))

def preprocess_images(image_path, img_height, img_width, mode):
    img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
    #convert 3-channel image to 1-channel
    img = img.convert(mode)
    img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img) 
    img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)   
    img_tensor /= 255.0
    img_tensor = tf.reshape(img_tensor, img_tensor.shape[:3])
    return tf.keras.backend.eval(img_tensor)
```

When I make predictions, I always get the result "Image is 5".So, I have 2 questions:
- How can I get the other classes [0-9] as output?
- Can I get better accuracy by increasing the number of data ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR;

Your `load_data()` function is to blame - you need to return the labels of the datasets as an integer rather than the string filepath

#### Much fuller explanation:

> Can I get better accuracy by increasing the number of data ?

In general, yes.

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with your *model*. I obviously don't have access to the dataset you have created but I can test it on the MNIST dataset (which your dataset is presumably trying to mirror):

```py
(train_data, train_labels),(test_data, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
  ])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_data, train_labels, batch_size=10, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

Having done so, we can train to an accuracy of roughly 93%:

`Test accuracy: 0.9275`

Your inference code then also works as expected on the test data:

```py
predictions = model.predict(test_data)

for i in range(len(predictions)):
    print("Image", i , "is", np.argmax(predictions[i]))
```

giving the output, you'd expect:

```
Image 0 is 7
Image 1 is 2
Image 2 is 1
Image 3 is 0
Image 4 is 4
...
```

So we know the model *can* work. So is the difference in performance simply down to the size of your dataset (246) compared to MNIST (60000)?

Well this is an easy thing to test - we can take a similarly sized slice of the MNIST data and repeat the exercise:

```py
train_data = train_data[:246]
train_labels = train_labels[:246]

test_data = test_data[:62]
test_labels = test_labels[:62]
```

So this time I see a dramatic reduction in the accuracy (c. 66% this time)  but I can train the model to a much higher degree of accuracy than you are seeing even with a much smaller subset.

Therefore the issue has to be with your data pre-processing (or the dataset itself).

In fact, looking at you `load_data()` function, I can see that the problem lies in the labels you are generating. Your `labels` just appear to the the image path? You have this:

```py
# --snip--

for img_path in os.listdir(labels_path):
  labels.append(imagePath) ## <-- this does not look right!

# --snip--
```

Whereas you need to populate `labels` with the integer value for the category your image belongs to (for the mnist digits this is an integer between 0 and 9)

Comment: Thank you so much @Stewart_R for your help. The problem was actually with the data pre-processing as you suggested. I also modified the tags in int and it works!!!